# Does Dask read_csv supports http web requests?

Tags: dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd  
df=dd.read_csv('http://www.example.data')
```

**Error:**

> ValueError: Unknown protocol http

**NOTE:** http_proxy and https_proxy both set

**python version:** 3.6.1

**`dask` version:** 0.14.3

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way hope this helps others also

`import pandas as pd`
  `import dask.dataframe as dd`
  `pdf=pd.read_csv('url_path')`
  `ddf=dd.from_pandas(pdf,npartitions=n)`

Answer (score 0):

Dask *does* support reading directly from HTTP(S), with a few caveats on the server capabilities and file size. Globs are not supported.
Your version of Dask is [over a year](https://github.com/dask/dask/releases?after=0.16.1) old, however - you should update.